# Reuse standard menus in Eclipse RCP4 application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I want to reuse standard menus from the Eclipse IDE in my RCP4 application (e.g. Windows->Preferences). 
In Eclipse RCP3 applications you simply have to add a menuContribution to the plugin.xml to achieve this. 
I tried the same for my RCP4 application but without success. Is there another way to add standard menus to a RCP4 application?

Comment: Are you asking about an e4 application using the Application.e4xmi?

Comment: Yes the question is about an e4 application using Application.e4xmi.

Comment: You can't reuse 3.x style menus and dialogs in an e4 application. What do you want to use exactly?

Comment: I want to reuse for instance the preference dialog, the perspective dialog and the new project wizard. I can use these dialogs by using the eclipse compatibility layer as described in the tutorial [link](http://dirksmetric.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/tutorial-eclipse-rcp-e4-with-3-x-views-like-project-explorer-properties-etc). But I want to make sure that I understand correctly that without using the compatibility layer I have to code everything myself. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pure e4 application which is not using the 3.x compatibility layer you have to construct all the menus and dialogs yourself.

For preferences you can use the JFace `org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog` which is a simpler version of the normal preferences dialog, but you don't get the preference page extension point (or any existing pages) so you have to craft all that yourself.